# grails mongo transaction rollback with save(flush:true)?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have an issueInstance and which has many issueItemInstances,

and one issueItemInstance has one receiptItemInstance(many-to-one),

when issueInstance.save(flush:true, failOnError:true),

I'd like recalculate receiptItemInstance.quantity by looping issueItemInstances to get all other saved issueItemInstance.quantity(many-to-one),

and when !receiptItemInstance.validate()(e.g. quantity too big),

I'd like to rollback,

But it seems doesn't work with 1.static transactional = 'mongo' and 2. Issue.withTransaction

when throw exception,the issueInstance and issueItemInstances would not be deleted.

if only with save(), It'd not recalculate correct because issueItemInstance not saved yet.

Is there any hint or any way but manual?

I use MongoDB GORM ':mongodb:3.0.1'

Thank you very much,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Issue.withTransaction { status ->
    Issue issueInstance // Get issue instance
    def receiptItemInstance // get receipt item instance

    if (!receiptItemInstance.validate()) {
        status.setRollbackOnly()
        return   // Exit the transaction block
    }
    // Conitune with your code
}
```